# Quais são as formas de armazenamento de dados no browser?

Tags: html5

Eu preciso armazenar informações em formato JSON direto no navegador, ouvi falar do `localStorage` do HTML5 porém ele possui limites de armazenamento que eu gostaria de ampliar se possível, caso não seja existem alternativas? Não gostaria de usar *cookies*.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [esse artigo da wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size), traduzido livremente para o português:

> ## Tamanho de armazenamento
>
> Web storage provêm muito mais capacidade (5 MB por origem no Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox e Opera; 10 MB por campo de armazenamento no Internet Explorer; 25 MB por origem em dispositivos rodando BlackBerry 10) comparado a 4 kb (por volta de 1000 vezes menos espaço) disponível para cookies.

Isso parece espaço o suficiente para a grande maioria das aplicações. Não existe, no entanto, uma forma de expandir o limite de armazenamento, a não ser que uma origem comece a consumir mais espaço do que era anteriormente permitido para ela e isso não é padronizado através dos navegadores.

Uma alternativa parece ser usar o `IndexedDB` ([*"MDN - Usando IndexedDB"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/IndexedDB/Usando_IndexedDB)). Também não há um limite de dados padronizado (o Firefox não impõe um limite, com o tamanho máximo de 50 MB para cada entrada, e o Chrome calcula o limite de dados relativo ao espaço disponível para cada usuário, então também não poderia ser confiável para tamanhos arbitrários).

Acredito que deva testar com o `localStorage` e caso não consiga fazer sua aplicação rodar dentro de um limite de 5 MB testar outras soluções. A API do `IndexedDB` parece ser relativamente bem suportada (confira o http://caniuse.com/).