# tem como criar txt com js?

Tags: javascript, html5, funções

Ae galera tenho um JS que tem umas funções que pega o nome do player, posiçãox, posiçãoy, level, imagem etc. Eu quero salvar esses dados em um dB, o usuário faz login com a conta e acessa os dados com um JS, para visualizar as informacoes.

Sera que posso fazer isso com um JS e php?

Ou posso gravar em um txt, e capturar com JS na pasta BD do host do site.

Existe como criar um txt com no host do site com puro JS por exemplo cria grava le e apaga dados no txt com JS.

Comment: Só pra deixar claro: você quer fazer isso no servidor ("host do site") ou no cliente ("guest do site")? A resposta do Carlos me parece ser uma solução no lado cliente (e exclusiva do IE, se não me engano), outras seriam usar local storage ou IndexedDB... Uma solução no lado do servidor exigiria uma plataforma própria pra isso (seja PHP ou qualquer outra linguagem, inclusive JavaScript - node.js). Relacionado: ["Armazenamento no browser"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51889/215)

Comment: Queria usar no servidor onde só poderia editar o arquivo com login.

Comment: Na minha opinião esse é um assunto muito amplo pra ser abordado em uma única pergunta (pois envolve programar no lado servidor, fazer login, salvar dados, restringir o acesso). Sugiro começar com alguns [tutoriais de PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) (ou outra plataforma, depende do que o seu servidor suporta), certamente eles vão cobrir boa parte das suas dúvidas. Leia também sobre [AJAX](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info) (pois me parece que você está tentando fazer uma espécie de jogo, então você deve precisar disso - ou de websockets, mas aí já é mais complicado).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O JavaScript é uma linguagem do lado do cliente e por isso bem limitada no que respeita acesso a ficheiros do cliente. Isto é por razões de segurança, para evitar que programas possam fazer ataques ao utilizador.

Existe uma biblioteca que grava ficheiros via JavaScript e funciona em Browsers modernos. Ela baseia-se no suporte de HTML5, que browsers antigos não têm, e usa o "Guardar como" ("Save as") que o browser expõe ao JavaScript.

**Dá uma olhada no Github:** https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
**Euma demo aqui:** http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: sim sergio so que eu queria que o arquivo focasse em um servidor, para servir como banco de dados, ja que o js nao tem conexao com mysql pensei que poderia simular um banco de dados com um txt, estou tentado com ajax, mas sua resposta me ajudou muito vlw.

Comment: @adailtonmoraes usa AJAX para ligar ao servidor. Usar um ficheiro como base de dados para JS não é viável. A minha resposta é em resposta à pergunta que colocaste sobre como criar um ficheiro com JS.

Comment: ok vou usar ajax mas so vi o ajax ser usado com formularios e eu preciso de usar esses dados em variaveis js, pra ler os dados, em variaveis.

Comment: @adailtonmoraes podes enviar o que quiseres com AJAX. Aceita um objeto com o que quiseres. Faz outra pergunta se precisares de ajuda. Se a minha resposta solucionou esta pergunta podes marcar como aceite.

Comment: Aqui não aparece a opção aceite e nem tem como eu pontuar Voces como faco isso.

Comment: @adailtonmoraes dá uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Comment: Pronto já aproveitar sua resposta

Answer (score 0):

Sim, da pra fazer com Javascript.(Exclusivo para IE) Vou explicar:

```
//Cria Objeto ActiveX
var dados = new ActiveXObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”);

//Função para gravar o arquivo
function GravaArquivo(arq,texto){
//pasta a ser salvo o arquivo
var pasta=”C:/Documents and Settings/Computador2/Desktop/LerGravartxtcomJS/”;
//se o parametro arq que é o nome do arquivo vier vazio ele salvará o arquivo com o nome “Sem Titulo”
if(arq==””){arq=”Sem Titulo”;}
//carrega o txt
var esc = dados.CreateTextFile(pasta+arq+”.txt”, false);
//escreve o que foi passado no parametro texto que é o texto contido no TextArea
esc.WriteLine(texto);
//fecha o txt
esc.Close();
}
//Função para abrir o arquivo
function AbreArquivo(arq){
//o parametro arq é o endereço do txt
//carrega o txt
var arquivo = dados.OpenTextFile(arq, 1, true);
//varre o arquivo
while(!arquivo.AtEndOfStream){
//escreve o txt no TextArea
document.getElementById(“texto”).value = arquivo.ReadAll();
}
//fecha o txt
arquivo.Close();
}
```

Comment: Dissera o em outro forum que esse método tinha sido bloqueado nos novos navegadores por isso não tinha testado.  Mas eu queria usar os dados numa variável por exemplo pega o nome do sujeito posiçãox, e posiçãoy, para manipular em variável, e outra função para gravar no txt em determinado tempo com um settimeout,   mas vales já ajudou muito vlw.

Comment: ActiveX é exclusivo para o Internet Explorer, ou estou enganado? (se sim, convém citar isso na resposta, pois o AP não mencionou plataforma)

Comment: ActiveXObject é para Windows. Para outras plataformas tem que fazer umas gambiarras. Antigamente, para funcionar no linux, usava-se o wine. Mas isso foi antigamente mesmo, lá para 2004 ~ 2009. Não sei dizer o que se usa hoje. E não esqueça que temos também, OS-X (Mac) e iOS e Android presentes no mercado.