# Como escrever e atualizar arquivo HTML com Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, arquivo

Então, estou pegando o conteúdo HTML de um site externo e renderizando no meu aplicativo híbrido. Até aí tudo bem. Tenho o seguinte código até então:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{{SuaUrlAqui}}',
   headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
      $(data).find('div#main').each(function(){
          $('div#noticias').prepend($(this).html()); //Mudar essa função aqui.
     });
   }
 });
```

O problema é que essa página no APP só vai funcionar se usuário estiver conectado com a internet. O que eu queria era salvar esse conteúdo em um arquivo e carregar desse arquivo as informações, que seriam atualizadas toda vez que o usuário abrisse o aplicativo conectado a internet. 
Existe alguma função que escreva o conteúdo que peguei em um arquivo .html com Jquery?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o localStorage do navegador do cliente para armazenar os dados da requisição e usá-lo como "offline cache" - https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, você pode checar a resposta em [tem como criar txt com js?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57061/tem-como-criar-txt-com-js)

Se é um app e você está usando jquery, provavelmente você está utilizando cordova para desenvolvimento(me confirme) então você também poderá usar o plugin de `File` do cordova:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Porém, como bem comentado pelo @**Romulo Gabriel** você pode usar `localstorage` e logo depois utilize uma função para checar se existe ou não conexão com a internet:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Comment: É isso aí, estou usando o cordova sim. Perfeito! Eu fiquei tão admirada que o JQuery fazia tudo que eu imaginava que nem pensei em outras formas pra fazer isso. Muito obrigada! Lucas Torres e @RômuloGabriel